# Task Scheduler - Show me a message when I lock my computer

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

Here's what I need to happen:

When I leave the office for the day, I lock my computer. We're supposed to fill out our timecards before leaving. I always forget to do it. I want a message to be displayed when I attempt to lock my computer asking me if I've filled out my timecard.

Here's what I've done, and why it doesn't work:

I created a task under Task Scheduler with action = "Display a message" and trigger = "On workstation lock". The problem with this is the task doesn't run until the workstation is literally locked and I don't see the message until I log back in again, which is pointless.

How can I do this so immediately after I press Ctrl-Alt-Del, but before my computer actually locks the message is displayed?

Any help would be appreciated. Bonus points awarded for the following:

1) Display the message only if after say 3:00pm, as I lock my computer multiple times a day and I would get the message every time. The 3:00pm constraint would assume I'm leaving for the day and therefore, it should ask me if I've filled it out.

2) At the end of the message, display "Would you like to visit the timecard site?" and display 2 buttons, Yes and No. If I click yes, the locking of the workstation is cancelled and the timecard site opens up in my browser. If no is clicked, the workstation goes on to be locked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pop your message up by calling [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx)() with the MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION flag.  That will cause the message box to be popped up on the console even if the logon screen is showing...

Comment: That will work. Thanks. I wrote a small program to run upon workstation lock. Now I'm able to incorporate the "only show it if it's past 3pm" criteria and the "open timecard site" if I answer No. My only complaint is after I click "No", My ws is locked, so I have to log back in to fill out my timecard, but that's not a big deal. It's reminding me to do it when I want to be reminded so I'm happy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is possible. When you press CTRL+ALT+DEL Windows handles that key press and you can't get a look in.

What you could do would be to put a shortcut on you desktop that locked the computer, but only after having shown the message you so desire.  I have a Lock Workstation shortcut on my desktop which is implemented with the following target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe User32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

You could quite easily write your own script, or maybe even a small app.  If the latter then you simply need to call the `LockWorkStation` function that is exported from `user32.dll`.

Answer (score -1):

change the action to a program, run this program

msg username message
ie: msg patrick Please remember to do this.